# How to make a page can be swiped left and right in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

In angular, how to make a page can be swiped left and right? The contents is a list of items, I would like to make it be viewed by swiping left and right, not by swiping up and down.

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let subtrip of trips">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-item text-wrap>
            <p> subtrip.id </p>
            <ion-avatar item-start >
              <img src="assets/img/car.png" style="...">
            </ion-avatar>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-w2hvcf check this

Comment: This is more of a CSS based question or a Hammerjs touch interaction-based question.

Comment: Use [ngx-useful-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-useful-swiper)